# Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel when downloading file via Powershell DSC

Tags: powershell, powershell-dsc

I'm trying to download a file via by invoking a web request inside a Powershell DSC.

When i execute the script i get the error

```
PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_ScriptResource  failed to execute Set-
TargetResource functionality
with error message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not 
establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

If i invoke the web request with the same headers and proxy outside of DSC, the request succeeds. What can i do to make the request work inside DSC?

```
Script DownloadArtifact{

        GetScript = 
        {
           Result = ('True' -in (Test-Path -Path "C:\Temp\BuildPackage\MyAPI.zip"))
        }
        SetScript = {

               $outfile = "C:\Temp\BuildPackage\MyAPI.zip"

                $headers = @{"Authorization"="Basic <redacted>"}

                $uri = "https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/_apis/build/builds/10374/artifacts/?artifactName=MyAPI&%24format=zip"

                Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile $outfile -Headers $headers -Proxy "http://proxy:8080"

                Unblock-File -Path $outfile;
            }
            TestScript = 
            {
                Test-Path -Path "C:\Temp\BuildPackage\MyAPI.zip"
            }           
    }
```

Incidentally i get the same error when using `[xRemoteFile]` too.

Answer (score 0):

try add this before Invoke-WebRequest

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"
```